# How many types of flat files we can use in SQL-Loader in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle

Anyone tell me how many types of flat files in SQL loader in oracle

Comment: What do you call a "type of flat files"?

Comment: Technically, the answer is just "Yes"

Comment: @Bohemian, technically, the answer to a question worded like "How many ..." should be numeric :)

Comment: @jeff but the question is not “how many...”, the question is “**can anyone tell me** how many...”, to which the answer is “yes, someone can tell you how many” :)

Comment: oh my goodness, I've been out-pedanted :)

Answer (score 2):

Oracle supports the below types of flat files.

**When using flat files as sources**:

1. You can read from character data set files or binary flat files.
2. You can read from delimited files, fixed length files, or XML files.
3. You can use flat file operators in SQL*Loader mappings to read from flat files directly, or you can add an external table and access the flat file data in a mapping using SQL and PL/SQL.
4. You can also add flat file operators in code template based mappings and leverage code templates that are specifically constructed for files or the generic SQL code templates which leverages a built-in JDBC driver for files.

**When using flat files as targets**:

1. You can use only character data set files. Binary flat files are not supported as targets.
2. You can write to delimited files and fixed length files.
3. You can use flat file operators to write data to flat files.

For more information look for 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/owb.112/e10582/defining_flatfiles.htm#WBDOD10539

Answer (score 0):

Any type of Flat files as far as you can make control file to understand it how to load the data. I mean to say any delimiter separated file like comma or tab separated file or you can mention the position of data in terms of a number of characters.
Files in excel format or pdf are not supported as they are encoded files.